# Django: Image Resizing & Compression

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project in which users can upload images.

Here's the view:

```
class AllPictures(models.Model):
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    # But before saving the image i'm compressing & resizing it, here's how
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.profile:
            img = Image.open(self.profile)
            resize = img.resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            new_image = BytesIO()
            resize.save(new_image, format=img.format, quality=75)
            temp_name = self.profile.name
            self.profile.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(new_image.getvalue()), save=False)
        super(AllPictures, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the problem is that when I upload images instead of saving them directly into `profile_image` folder, it creates a long series of sub-sub-folders for every new image & saves that image inside a separate folder.

So, the `profile_image` folder looks something like this,

```
profile_image
    my_image.png
----profile_image
        new_image.png 
--------profile_image
            all_image.png
------------profile_image
                images.png
----------------profile_image
                    picture.png
--------------------profile_image
                        another_pic.png

                        & so on . . .
```

How can we save all new images in just 1 folder & prevent the formation of these sub-folders?

Comment: try this profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image/', blank=True)

Comment: @Exprator Sir, it's still creating sub folders by own. What should i do?

Comment: use that / after the profile_image in upload_to and try once

Comment: @Exprator Yes Sir, I added the / & then ran makemigrations & migrate. But still caused same error. Sir, just now I removed the entire Compression & Resizing code from the model & everything is working fine now. But I need Resize & Compression functionality, I don't know where is the problem in this code :( . Can you please find it out?

Comment: remove this line and check again `self.profile.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(new_image.getvalue()), save=False)`

Comment: @Exprator Sir, After removing this line it's neither resizing nor compressing the new images!

Comment: I believe it is because your `temp_name` already contains `profile_image`. And you're passing it along to the storage class of the same field. That means Django will upload `profile_image/filename.jpg` to `profile_image` directory. Solution: **Split the filename from temp_image and pass it to save method**

Comment: @anupsabraham Sir, i'm new in django. Can you explain a bit more how can I split the name & pass it to save method?

Comment: Use `os.path.split` to get the filename from the path. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.split
`temp_name = os.path.split(self.profile.name)[1]  # this will give you the filename`.

Comment: Before doing this, I suggest you to check what the value of `self.profile.name` is by printing it. I'm not sure about this myself. That is why I'm not adding it as an answer.

Comment: @anupsabraham Thank You very much Sir, it's working fine now :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)